# How can I create a new object from a JSON POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to create a new "Image" object on the Rails server from json using HTTP POST.

Here's the images_controller code:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @image = Image.new(params[:image])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to images_path }
        format.json { render :success => true }
      else
        format.html { render "new" }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end #respond_to
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
MyServer::Application.routes.draw do

  post 'images' => 'images#create'

end
```

I am using the Chrome extension "Simple REST client".
This the request:

```
URL: http://localhost:3000/images
METHOD: POST
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

Data:
{"image": { "title":"myImage", "url": "someUrl" } }
```

This is the response:

```
Status:500 Internal Server Error
Data:
<title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
      <h1>Template is missing</h1>
    <p>Missing template images/create, application/create with {:locale=&gt;[:en], :formats=&gt;[:json], :handlers=&gt;[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
      * &quot;c:/Users/XXX/workspaceRubyOnRails/my_server/app/views&quot;
    </p>
```

Running rake routes:
$ rake routes

```
images_edit GET  /images/edit(.:format) images#edit
 images_new GET  /images/new(.:format)  images#new
     images GET  /images(.:format)      images#index
      image GET  /images/:id(.:format)  images#show
     images POST /images(.:format)      images#create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the request to `http://localhost:3000/images.json` instead of `http://localhost:3000/images`.

Comment: unfortunately, still "500 Internal Server Error", Template is missing

Comment: Could you paste the routes related to the images? Do that by running `rake routes`.

Comment: Try changing your image success json to: `format.json { render :json => @image }`